# Fluorescent Light Bulb Issue

Tags: troubleshooting

**Can this burnt hole, and PCB tract that got burnt off be responsible for the whole PCB not working?**  The PCB is from a fluorescent light bulb.  The voltage was high enough to cross there and I heard a pop. **The voltage was high enough to ionize the air, and the PCB track got burnt off could that lead for the circuit not working?**  None of the components look burnt and everything else is seemingly ok.

[image: Pcb]

Just in case the crape of an image was bad, I added a better one.

Comment: What hole?  I don't see anything that looks like a hole in that crappy photograph.  You really should be able to see for yourself that the relevant parts of the picture are mostly black.  -1 for dumping slop on us, and closing because we can't tell what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'burnt hole' appears to have been a pad where a wire once entered the board.
It is not uncommon for such wire/board entries to form poor solder
connection, and heat up, become  intermittent, eventually come
apart.   So, find the loose wire that came out of the hole, and
try reconnecting it.

The pad may have come loose (search for it, and melted solder, before
trying to apply power).

If voltages are high enough, a carbonized area ('burnt') can cause
spurious conduction: with care (sometimes, with sandblasting) one
might be able to clean up the region and get the board back to function.

Answer (score 2):

I think the bent cut leads are too long and bridging the critical gaps marked in white silk screen white lines for dielectric breakdown.

This quality issue may have been the trigger with dust or humidity being a modulator that reduces breakdown voltage.

Comment: So not the burnt hole with the broken track?

Comment: I believe once a  breakdown occurred (arc) the high resistance paths to high current would burn the holes and track as secondary effects.  I've seen a gas tube used as overvoltage clamp protection without current limiting, trigger like an SCR and line voltage burnt a huge molten crater in the path of the line voltage tracks on board.

Comment: air has a breakdown of typ 1kV/mm (3kV/mm if dry and clean and flat surfaces), less if sharp needle points due to E field gradients